# Get an array of images in my web application?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

When I need one image I have this:

```
[Column(TypeName = "image")]
public byte[] Photo
{ get; set; }
```

But what do I do when I need more than one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Array or List.

```
    public class Photo
    {
      public byte[] Binary { get; set; }
    }

     var list=new List<Photo>();
```

Comment: Nice answer but instead of var=new List<Photo> I added 
public IList<Foto> FotosLugar;

Answer (score 1):

You need to store them in their own model and add it as a relationship, something like this:

```
public class Photo
{
  public byte[] Binary { get; set; }
}

public class ModelWithPhotos
{
  public virtual IList<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
}
```